# DATESINPERIOD and DATESBETWEEN not work properly when i use my SELECTEDVALUE date or MAX date

Tags: powerbi, dax

DATESINPERIOD and DATESBETWEEN work properly with this code :

```
`        DATESINPERIOD(
            FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode],
            DATE(2023,01,31),
            -6, MONTH
        )`


`        DATESBETWEEN (
            FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode],
            DATE(2023,01,31),
            DATE(2023,06,31)
        )`
```

but when i use my selectedvalue or max date, i don't have the same output like the code above

```
`previous 6 months = 
VAR selected_date = SELECTEDVALUE(FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Arriere N],
        DATESINPERIOD(
            FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode],
            selected_date,
            -6, MONTH
        )
    )`
```

My slicer date is dropdown not between date [date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYO73.png)

I already try to get year and month and day :

```
`DATE(YEAR(selected_date),MONTH(selected_date),DAY(selected_date))`
```

but still return all 12 months with 2024 date, sometimes blank value

Comment: What format is `FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
previous 6 months = 
VAR selected_date = LASTDATE(dim_date[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Arriere N],
        ALL(FACT_monthly_Arriere),
        DATESINPERIOD(
            FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode],
            selected_date,
            -6, MONTH
        )
    )
```

Added `ALL(...)` and changed `selected_date`

This one might be more efficient depending on your fact table size.

```
previous 6 months = 
VAR selected_date = LASTDATE(dim_date[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Arriere N],
        ALL(dim_date),
        DATESINPERIOD(
            dim_date[Date],
            selected_date,
            -6, MONTH
        )
    )
```

Comment: I already try it but not work,
about FACT_monthly_Arriere[Date periode] this is a lookupvalue between dim_date

Comment: but the same return value even if i use dim_date

Comment: Thanks for that - updated the answer.

Comment: still wrong value, the problem is about selected_date in dateinperiod or datesbetween
i struggle with this bug since yesterdat TT

Comment: If you create a new measure like: `selectedDate= RETURN SELECTEDVALUE(dim_date[Date], TODAY())` does it show correctly when using your slicer?